# Display a .tpl file in product error page in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm using PS version 1.5.6.2. When we disable a product or if product gets deleted then we see a message like 
THERE IS 1 ERROR
This product is no longer available.
I want to add a 404.tpl file in place of this. Is it possible ?

I have gone through the productcontroller.php and added some codes to display the tpl file but didn't get any success.

Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the template file yourself, the `Tools` class has a method `display404Error` for this:

```
// check whatever you want in the method your want
if (!$this->product->available_for_order) {
    Tools::display404Error();
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I don't find this code in my product controller can you tell me where can I find this ? another thing is I just want to show a file instead of the error. Is it possible ? can we add a file instead of the tools::display404error ? please shed some light on it.

Comment: You won't find this code it's the code you should use. Basically you can check if the product is available in the `init` method or something like that. This will display the 404 page, if you want to display another page you can check the `Tools` method code to do whatever you want